# String date into Epoch time

Tags: java, android, json, datetime, epoch

I am little bit confused in dates. I am currently working on the weather app and everything works fine .. I just wanna handle this type of format into my own desirable format.

```
2017-09-10T18:35:00+05:00
```

I just wanna convert this date into Epoch Time and then I settle the date in my desire format ::

for J-SON

or i wanna convert this date into less figure i.e Sun , 9 september 9:23 Am etc.

http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/257072?apikey=JTgPZ8wN9VUy07GaOODeZfZ3sAM12irH&language=en-us&details=true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` instance to parse the string into a `Date` object:

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parser.parse("2017-09-10T18:35:00+05:00");
```

And then use another SimpleDateFormat to display it:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMMMM h:mm a");
String formatted = format.format(date); // Sun, 10 September 1:35 PM
```

Comment: i appreciate your time , would you guide me the date in string (input) i want that date and display only few things i mean month date and time .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to extract the month, day, and time from the input date?

Comment: the date above i retrieve is like 2017-09-10T18:35:00+05:00 when i show this date in my app its look bad to me so i want the date to be  look like                  d i.e Sun, 10 September 9:40 am etc ..

Comment: Thanks that what exactly i want .. !

Answer (score 5):

### ThreeTenABP

The other answers are correct, but outdated before they were written. These days I recommend you use the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`. Your date-time string format is ISO 8601, which the modern classes “understand” as their default.

Can you use the modern API on Android yet? Most certainly! The JSR-310 classes have been backported to Android in the **ThreeTenABP** project. All the details are in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

```
    long epochTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-09-10T18:35:00+05:00")
            .toInstant()
            .getEpochSecond();
```

The result is 1505050500.

Edit: Arvind Kumar Avinash correctly points out in a comment: You do not need to convert an `OffsetDateTime` to an `Instant` to get the epoch seconds. You can simply use `OffsetDateTime#toEpochSecond`.

Example of how to convert this into a human-readable date and time:

```
    String formattedDateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochTime)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Lusaka"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMMM h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This produces `Sun, 10 September 3:35 PM`. Please provide the correct region and city for the time zone ID you want. If you want to rely on the device’s time zone setting, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. See [the documentation of DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String)) for the letters you may use in the format pattern string, or use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime()`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(org.threeten.bp.format.FormatStyle)) for one of your locale’s default formats.

Comment: and if i solve this epochTime using Date , SimpleDateFormat will  i get the correct Date.. ?

Comment: because i tried other method and i keep getting date like Thu, 1 ,1 1970 5:01 Am

Comment: Don’t do that. The point is to avoid the outdated classes, including `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: then how i am supposed to convert this 1505050500 into real date or time

Comment: it gives usage of API documented @Since 1.8+ ?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you links to the wrong version of the API documentation. It should work, though. Still better, use the proper [TheeTen Backport API docs](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/). @SaadZahoor

Comment: Good Answer, but `OffsetDateTime.parse` would be more appropriate than `ZonedDateTime.parse`.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque, I don’t know how `ZonedDateTime` slipped through there, you are certainly correct. Fixed.

Comment: You do not need to convert an `OffsetDateTime` to an `Instant` to get the epoch seconds. You can simply use [`OffsetDateTime#toEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Correct, thank you. I have pasted your helpful comment into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDate formatter to parse you date as string into epoch

```
        String input = "2017-09-10T18:35:00+05:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        try {
            Date date = sf.parse(input);
            long dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds = date.getTime();
            //if you want this in seconds then
            long dateInEpochFormatInSeconds = date.getTime()/1000L;
            //if you want to show only date month and year then
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
             String date = sdf.format(dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds);
             //This date String will contain the date in dd-MM-yyyy format
        } catch (ParseException| ArithmeticException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i  appreciate your time , would you guide me the date in string (input) i want that date and display only few things i mean month date and time .

Comment: Then you can use another SimpleDateFormat for your purpose
long dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds = date.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds);
This will give you date month and time in the date String

Comment: if you want to show time also then you can use "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" in the arguments

Comment: i already tried this one it give me the very first date i.e Thu , 1 1 1970 5:01 AM  here what i tried

Comment: see my answer comment to view the code what i tried

Comment: see my answer comment

Comment: I cannot see what you have tried. If you have give the correct input date as String then you will get your desired date as output

Comment: 2017-09-10T20:35:00+05:00 this is the date i fetch

Comment: you need to use dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds not dateInEpochFormatInSeconds because String date = sdf.format(dateInEpochFormatInMilliSeconds); takes time in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```
    String time_at_which_weather_capture = "Time : ";


    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,d M yyyy h:MM a");
    long timeInMillieSec = 0 ;
    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(readyToUpdate.getTime());
        timeInMillieSec = date.getTime();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   time.setText(time_at_which_weather_capture + String.valueOf(time_fetcher(timeInMillieSec)));



public String time_fetcher (long time_coming_to_its_original_form) {

    Date date = new Date (time_coming_to_its_original_form);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d M yyyy h:MM a");
    return sdf.format(date);



}
```