# How to parse "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" date format to simple in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, date, datetime-parsing

How do I can parse this date `2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00` to `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm` format in Android?

And what does `T` between `09` and `11` mean?
Thanks.

I don't know how the back-end developer got this format.
I am using Java.

Comment: How did you get this format? `2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00`

Comment: Could you update you question and tags to say if you are using Kotlin or Java please.

Comment: I renewed answer

Comment: This format is from Solr .

Comment: search engine??? i thought it's died)))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do your search and research job properly before asking a question here. This question has been asked and answered a number of times already, and you would have found a good answer faster through your search engine than through asking the same question one more time.

Comment: Or of [String date into Epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142198/string-date-into-epoch-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using java, you can use `SimpeDateFormat` with patterns:

```
        String date = "2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00";
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = dateformat.parse(date /*your date as String*/);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String formattedDate = output.format(d);

        Log.d("Date format", "output date :" + formattedDate);
```

The output is :

> D/Date format: output date :09.01.2018 09:11

**EDIT :** Thanks to @OleV.V., for API > 26, or using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)  we can use

[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), we can do something like that

```
    String date = "2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    DateTimeFormatter formatterOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
    LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

    String formattedDate = formatterOut.format(parsedDate);
    Log.d("Date format", "output date :" + formattedDate);
```

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree, but it require API > 26

Comment: It does not, @E.Abdel. Add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project and you’re going on low API levels too. And who knows, the asker may be on level 26 already. At least recommend this solution first and let the asker decide for herself/himself whether to go for something inferior.

Comment: @OleV.V. I will check that, especially to see how much the apk size increase after adding the lib, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Here is a tested example in Java:

```
String dateString = "2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00";

String inPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
String outPattern = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm";

SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inPattern, Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outPattern, Locale.getDefault());

try {
    Date inDate = inFormat.parse(dateString);
    String outDate = outFormat.format(inDate);
    Log.e("TEST", outDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is a tested example in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/):

```
val dateString = "2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00"

val inPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
val outPattern = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm"

val inFormat = SimpleDateFormat(inPattern, Locale.getDefault())
val outFormat = SimpleDateFormat(outPattern, Locale.getDefault())

val inDate = inFormat.parse(dateString)
val outDate = outFormat.format(inDate)

Log.e("TEST", outDate)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I can do similar thing by Java?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Java implementation.

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

    String backendDateTimeString = "2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(backendDateTimeString);
    String presentationDateTimeString = dateTime.format(desiredFormatter);
    System.out.println(presentationDateTimeString);
```

This prints:

> 09.01.2018 11:11

Please note: I am using uppercase `HH` in the format pattern string. This indicates hour of day from 00 through 23. In the question you used lowercase `hh`, which in a format pattern string means hour with AM or PM from 01 through 12, so 00:33 would come out as 12:33 and 15:47 as 03:47. I didn’t think you intended this.

The format that your backend developer got, `2018-01-09T11:11:02.0+03:00`, is ISO 8601. It’s widespread, and it’s the international standard, so it’s good that s/he got that. The funny `T` in the middle indicates the start of the time part to separate it from the date part. The one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` method parses ISO 8601, which is why we didn’t need any formatter for parsing. `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` are classes from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (API level 26 and up) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages (my code was tested with these imports).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)