# 2021-04-05T16:25:45.000+00:00 Time stamp change in SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp

My Code

```java
String date = "2021-04-05T16:25:45.000+00:00";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
Date parsedDate = null;
try {
    parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(parsedDate);
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: You have got a parse exception. Check the output from `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: Does this answer your question in whole or in part? [Generic support for ISO 8601 format in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040143/generic-support-for-iso-8601-format-in-java-6). And/or this? [String date into Epoch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142198/string-date-into-epoch-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Use for example this output formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter OUTPUT_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN"));
```

With it do:

```
    String date = "2021-04-05T16:25:45.000+00:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
    String formattedDate = dateTime.format(OUTPUT_FORMATTER);
    
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output:

> 2021-04-05 04:25:45 PM

You may use a different locale for the output formatter as appropriate for your requirements. The choice of locale determines which strings are used for AM and PM.

I am exploiting the fact that the string that you have got is in ISO 8601 format. `offsetDateTime` parses this format as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

### What went wrong in your code?

You tried using a format pattern string of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` for a date string of `2021-04-05T16:25:45.000+00:00`. The `'Z'` in single quotes in the format pattern string means that your date string must end in a literal `Z`. When instead it ended in `+00:00`, parsing failed with a `ParseException`. If you didn’t see the output from `e.printStackTrace();` in your code, you have got a serious flaw in your project setup that you should fix before worrying about how to parse the date string. In any case, since parsing failed, `parsedDate` kept its initial value of `null`, which caused `outputFormat.format(parsedDate)` to throw the `NullPointerException` that you did see.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)